# Syntax for passing REST data in Robot Framework

Tags: rest, robotframework

See below code, specifically data part. Robot does not like this.

```
*** Test Cases ***
Add Patient
    Log  Add Patient
    [Tags]  Add_Patient
    ${number}=  Generate Random Number  ${4}
    ${data}=  {"patients": [ new "sponsor": "test1", "protocol": "Blue18-B18VP1","site_number": "1001","integration_id": int_id_${number},"subject_number": "RT0001","subject_status": "T","randomization_date": "01Jan2017", "treatment_id": "B18VP2"} ]}
    Create Session  sw3  ${ENVIRONMENT_TO_RUN_AGAINST}  debug=3
    ${resp}=  Post Request  sw3  ${ENVIRONMENT_TO_RUN_AGAINST}/api/v1/test1/patients
    \  ...  Content-Type:application/json
    \  ...  Authorization:authkey02 Accept=application/json
    \  ...  data=${data}
```

Giving error as follows:

```
Creating keyword failed: No keyword with name '{"patients": [ new "sponsor": "test1", "protocol": "Blue18-B18VP1","site_number": "1001","integration_id": int_id_${number},"subject_number": "RT0001","subject_status": "T","randomization_date": "01Jan2017", "treatment_id": "B18VP2"} ]}' found.
```

Comment: What do you expect `new "sponsor"` to do, or is that a typo?

Answer (score 0):

It's important to pass data as dynamic values and not as string. So instead of creating your string create lists and/or dictionaries - if you then pass it over, it will be represented as JSON. For example:

```
${patients} =    Create List    ${valueA}    ${valueB}    ${valueC}
${data} =    Create Dictionary    patients=${patients}
${resp} =    Post Request    alias=${alias}    uri=${uri}    data=${data}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Setting variables

You have to use a keyword such as [Set variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38212206/tkinter-multiple-buttons-colour-change) or [Catenate](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Catenate) to create a string, which is what that error message is trying to tell you. Catenate is useful when you want to define the string across multiple lines.

For example:

```
${data}=  Catenate
...   {"patients": 
...     [ new "sponsor": "test1", 
...       "protocol": "Blue18-B18VP1",
...       "site_number": "1001",
...       "integration_id": int_id_${number},
...       "subject_number": "RT0001",
...       "subject_status": "T",
...       "randomization_date": "01Jan2017", 
...       "treatment_id": "B18VP2"
...     ]
...  }
```

However, the data in your question seems to be invalid JSON. I don't know what you're attempting to do with `[ new "sponsor": "test1" ...`. Regardless, to solve the problem of creating a variable that contains json data, you need to use a keyword in the first cell after the variable name.

### Defining the header dictionary

You must pass the headers as a dictionary, not as individual arguments. You can create a dictionary with `Create Dictionary` like so:

```
&{headers}=  Create Dictionary
...  Content-Type=application/json
...  Authorization=authkey02 
...  Accept=application/json
```

### Making the POST request

To make the post request you should use named arguments, passing in the headers and data like so:

```
${resp}=  Post Request  sw3  ${ENVIRONMENT_TO_RUN_AGAINST}/api/v1/test1/patients
...  headers=${headers}
...  data=${data}
```

---

for more examples, look at the test cases for the requests library itself:

https://github.com/bulkan/robotframework-requests/blob/master/tests/testcase.txt

Comment: Ah new was a typo apologies :)

Comment: Still getting an error with that change...Keyword 'RequestsLibrary.Post Request' got multiple values for argument 'data'.

Comment: @user3414559: I've updated my answer with more details.